# How to change home screen for Jailbreak Device programming

Tags: ios, jailbreak, tweak, logos

I'm a newbie in iOSOpenDev. I want to change the home screen on my jailbroken device. I use iOSOpenDev with Logos tweak to implement this

```
%hook SBUIController

- (void)finishLaunching
{    
    SBUIController *uicontroller = (SBUIController *)[%c(SBUIController) sharedInstance];

    // Get _contentView & _iconsView from SBUIController
    UIView* _contentView = [uicontroller valueForKey:@"_contentView"];
    UIView* _iconsView = [uicontroller valueForKey:@"_iconsView"];

    // Hidden _iconsView
    _iconsView.hidden = YES;

    // Add Sphere View
    SphereViewManager *sphere = [[SphereViewManager alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    sphere.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    sphere.tag = 20141201;
    [_contentView addSubview:sphere];
}
```

After SpringBoard is restarted, my home screen is loaded. But when I tap an app to launch, and then I press the HOME button, my device returns to the old home screen. How do I prevent my HOME screen from returning the the old view?

Comment: Have you looked at the `SBUIController` header to see what other methods in that class might get triggered when returning to the home screen (after closing an app)?